# Get numbers of difference in two strings javascript

Tags: javascript, string, diff

i have two string

```
const string1 = "usa(Country), with concealed(O), zipper(Closure)"
const string2 = "usa(Country), with(O), concealed zipper(Closure)"
```

I want to find diff in these two string for example in this scenario it is 2

Comment: But the diff isn't 2, I can see 8 minimum by just giving it a quick glance. What rules do you expect people to use given you can only see 2 differences? What have you tried and what did you fail on?

Comment: why is it two? what have you tried?

Comment: You mean the string has comma seperated  items and you want to find the number of diffs of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming the strings need to be compared based on the comma separations, but to be fair there isn't enough details in the question...

Split the strings by comma

```
// split function will be an array of strings
const split = (str, delimiter) => str.split(delimiter)
```

Apply the above function to both strings, and compare the results

```
// this uses lodash
// result will be an array, get the length
const result = _.difference(split(string1, ','), split(string2, ',')
```

If you're not going to use `lodash`, you can look up the vanilla JS implementation of `difference`

If order is important, you may need `_.xor`, but you can determine that with testing